# mySQL import failing on DECIMAL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to import some fields into a MySQL database, here is my import file...

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
 zip       VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,lat       DECIMAL(10,8) NOT NULL
,long      DECIMAL(11,8) NOT NULL
,data      VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
);
```

It is giving me the following error...

```
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'long DECIMAL(11,8) NOT NULL ,data VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL )' at line 4
```

It is not liking the `long` field that I am trying to set as `DECIMAL` type

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The clue is in the error message. The error is always at (or immediately to the left of) the first word in the error message: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: Incidentally, if you do the arithmetic, VARCHAR(3) probably doesn't make a whole lot of sense (but then again, I haven't actually done the arithmetic).

Comment: Can you elaborate at all?  Not sure I follow what you mean by do the arithmetic

Comment: Well, this is a bit geeky, but... CHAR(3) always requires 3 bytes.

VARCHAR(3) always requires at least 1 byte. If the string is 2 characters in length, then it requires 3 bytes, and if it's 3 characters then it requires 4 bytes.

So, it comes down to what percentage of your strings are less than 2 characters in length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `long` is the reserved keyword in MySQL. Try using escaping like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(zip       VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,lat       DECIMAL(10,8) NOT NULL
,`long`    DECIMAL(11,8) NOT NULL
,data      VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
);
```

Or, what is better, try using another name. For latitude and longitude this might be `lat` and `lng` or `lat` and `lon`.

Comment: Try not using long. No one else does, and now we know why.

Comment: Thank you, it was staring me in the face all along!  I had reserved keywords in my checklist but hadn't spotted it